# Is it posible to change the underlying repository of an Sitecore XM Cloud Project

Tags: xm-cloud

While waiting for Github Enterprise to be setup we started off with a personal github account to connect to a Sitecore XM Cloud Project and set thing up.
So now I want to change the underlying repository of the XM Cloud Project to a github enterprices repository. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

I also went through the Sitecore CLI docs, but it doesn't seem to be possible to change this repository configuration.
Not sure if it makes sense to do so???

any thoughts are welcome
Cheers.

Comment: you can use same code for Enterprise account then change the repository in project detail XM cloud dashboard

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, it is not possible to change the repository for an XM Cloud project.

The only way to do this is too create a new project, create the required environments and migrate your content over.

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to a Sitecore Slack thread explaining a way to unlink and link another repository to an existing XM Cloud Project using the Sitecore XM Cloud Deploy API. I was able to unlink and link the project to a different Github Enterprise repository, but it was unable to build and deploy using the repository.

see:
https://sitecorechat.slack.com/archives/C03NXTAPKE3/p1697548161974009

Comment: The community Slack messages are deleted after 90 days, so you should make sure that anything relevant for the answer is copied into here as that link will be broken.

Comment: As mentioned above. This method does not work. Currently it is not possible to do this action. It is on the roadmap to enable this, but I don't have a timescale.

Answer (score 0):

You can unlink it using Sitecore XM Cloud Admin APIs but redeployment fails so currently it is not possible unless you delete all the sites and environments and the project and recreate and link it with the new repo.

There should be a way to do that but does not seem to be available right now.